# How to cross compile a C++ file with LTIB

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I have installed LTIB from freescale (by way of Congatec) and would like to compile a "hello, world" program.  gcc gives me the native executable.  How do I compile for my ARM processor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `./ltib -m shell`.  In this mode all of the standard tools are setup to allow `./configure` and other setups to build for an **ARM** by default.  From this shell `gcc -o hello hello.cpp` will create an executable for you.  It will be setup for your *rootfs*, be it *uCLibc* or *glibc*.  You can also take external open-source packages and run the `./configure` - `make` cycle.

The documentation in the [LTIB FAQ](http://ltib.org/documentation-LtibFaq) has much more information on using **LTIB**.  **LTIB** typically installs tools in the */opt/freescale* directory.  If you are not using a custom compiler you will find the compiler under */opt/freescale* and can use it directly.  In this directory, the compiler will be named something like `arm-none-linux-gnuabi-gcc`.  With the `./ltib -m shell`, it is aliased to `gcc` as are many other standard commands for cross-building.

Comment: So much easier than finding the path: /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++

Answer (score 6):

You need to install a cross compiler for ARM. gcc on your machine is the native compiler, a cross compiler has a different prefix that determines the target architecture, operating system and libc. In your case, the target system has probably an ARM architecture, is running a Linux kernel with the GNU libc.

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hello hello.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the -march=name option in the gcc man page. The exact architecture you will specify depends on the version of ARM you need to compile for. v5 ARM example:

```
gcc -o ARM.exe -march=armv5 source.c
```

Comment: the gcc binary has to be built for that family for that to work, an x86 gcc for example wont build for arm. (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

First move to the LTIB folder.
cd "ltib folder"
Then enter the ltib shell
./ltib -m shell
then compile using
gcc -static "program name" .c -o "program name".sabre
Then run the command
file "program name".sabre